# Delete data older than a month for every sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel file with many sheets, and I would like to filter old data at the end of the month and delete it. I can't always clear the data on the first, and sometimes users will work on the workbook before I can set it up for the current month.

This is the code I currently have:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long

    response = MsgBox("Tem a Certeza que quer Limpar todo os Dados?", vbYesNo)
    If response = vbNo Then Exit Sub

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Formularios" Then
        If ws.Name <> "Coordenador" Then
            If ws.Name <> "LookupList" Then
                With ws
                    .Unprotect Password:=pass
                    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                    LastCol = .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
                End With
                With Rng
                    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count).Rows.Delete
                End With
                With ws
                    .AutoFilterMode = False
                    If .FilterMode = True Then
                        .ShowAllData
                    End If
                    .Protect Password:=pass
                End With
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I get an Error 1004 object on this line:

```vb
.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count).Rows.Delete
```

Comment: @YowE3K: the With block variable is Rng... but this Resize still looks fishy.

Comment: @Excelosaurus Ahh - I hadn't notice that

Comment: The next thing I was going to point out is that the `Offset(1, 0)` will mean that some of the cells that were visible will now be excluded, and some that were excluded will now be included - e.g. if the visible cells were `A5:A10,A14:A20` then the `Offset` will make that `A6:A11,A15:A21`.

Comment: Does the line just need to be changed to `.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`?

Comment: OP tries to exclude the header row. Working on an answer.

Comment: And the last thing I was going to mention was ... are any cells visible?  You can't do anything with `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` if that is `Nothing`.

Comment: Use `.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: @YowE3k Usually on this workbook there is 2 types of data, this months data and last months. The idea is it deletes last month. So the filter would keep last months data visible

Comment: Actually, using the offset first (and thus including one row below the original range) will **ensure** that there is always a visible row :)

Comment: @jeeped With your code I get error 1004: Cannot use that code on overlapping selections

Comment: I think your .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth is missing ,Operator:=xlFilterDynamic.   When I ran your code it hid all rows including those with today's date.

Comment: @mooseman maybe thats part of the problem, but it didn't fix it just by adding it

Comment: Look closely at `LastCol = .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` . Do you see what's wrong?

Comment: Hint: try it as `LastCol = .cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column`

Comment: @Jeeped I started this code with a record macro. and built it from there. Interesting enough your last change did let the code run until there was one sheet that didn't have any data for last month (I deleted manually for code testing) Thank you! I'm just going to add code for by any chance he finds an empty rng

Comment: Use my cbool check for visible filtered rows found below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the form I typically use.

```
        With ws
            .Unprotect Password:=pass
            LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            LastCol = .cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
            Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
        End With
        With Rng
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
            with .resize(.rows.count-1, .columns.count).offset(1, 0)
                if cbool(application.subtotal(103, .cells)) then
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
                end if
            end with
        End With
```

Comment: Simpler, better, safer than my answer (which would have destroyed the header row of an empty table).

Comment: This gives me the same error that I was getting with your new code :(

Comment: Took a note from @mooseman's comment and added xlFilterDynamic

Comment: Still getting the annoying Auto filter range class error

Comment: This is working for me now! Thank you all for the help

Comment: @Jeeped Last month this ran great now I'm having an error:
"Cannot use the command on overlapping selections" and it hightlighs: .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete any ideas why this would happen?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the initial range (rng) to be only the second row and took out the offset and resize.  Since the range is only used in this subroutine, why is it being resized?
I tested it with 5 or 6 dates in this month and last, even putting them out of order and it worked as expected.

```
sub stest()
            With Worksheets(1)

                LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1))
            End With
            With Rng
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:=xlFilterDynamic
                .offset(1,0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            End With
End Sub
```

Comment: See my comments re: `LastCol = .Range("A" & .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` above.

Comment: With no offset, you are going to delete the header row whether there are visible dates or not.

Comment: @Jeeped.  Yeah I see that, but what I don't understand is why the column is important, since only field1 (column A) is used in the filter and it is deleting the entire rows.  Yeah, the header would be deleted if there are no other visible rows.  I'll fix my answer